# Passing file from React app to Node app to upload to S3, file is undefined when defining the upload params?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, express

I'm trying to make my own personal resume using React and Node, and I've been having issues with the upload to AWS S3 for a few hours now.

I fire an event when submitting the form with the file :

```
onSubmitChange = () => {
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('url', this.state.url);
    data.append('name', this.state.name);
    data.append('description', this.state.description);
    data.append('filePath', this.state.file);

    fetch('http://localhost:3001/new-experience', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        body: data
        // body: JSON.stringify({
        //     url: this.state.url,
        //     name: this.state.name,
        //     description: this.state.description,
        //     filePath: this.state.file,
        // })
    })
    .then(resp => console.log(resp));
}
```

Which then triggers this

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWSAccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWSSecretKey,
    region: 'eu-west-3'
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
app.post('/new-experience', (req, res) => {
    const { url, name, description, filePath } = req.body;

    console.log(filePath);

    const params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket-xxxx',
        Body : fs.createReadStream(filePath),
        Key : "folder/test.png"
     };

    s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        //handle error
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
         }

        //success
        if (data) {
          console.log("Uploaded in:", data.Location);
        }
    });

    db('mael-landrin').insert({
        experienceurl: url,
        experiencename: name,
        experiencedescription: description
    })
    .into('experiences')
    .then(resp => res.status(200).send('Experience added'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
})
```

The console log in the 3rd line of the "/new-experience" route returns undefined, which I believe is why fs.createReadSream(filePath) gives undefined to the function, which is why I get the error.

The last console.log() in the React part gives me everything right, 3 strings and a file ( a .png file ).

```
Apple Website for Apple. https://www.apple.com/ File {name: "Entˆte Mozzarelline 25g x 8.jpg", lastModified: 1583766837712, lastModifiedDate: Mon Mar 09 2020 16:13:57 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 454282, …}
```

Anyone knows where it could come from ?

Answer (score 0):

The file object will not be present on your req.body. You need to install a third party module for file upload(of course there are "raw" ways to do it, but i don't know how and see no reason to do so):

```
npm i express-fileupload
```

In your express root file:

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload());
```

Then in your file upload route:

```
const { url, name, description} = req.body;
const fileObject = req.files.filePath;//"filePath" is misleading, but this is the name you chose.  
const fileData = fileObject.data;

const params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket-xxxx',
        Body : fileData,
        Key : "folder/test.png"
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably intended to do is to append file to data not file path. So do this

```
data.append('file', this.state.file);
```

You also need a middleware to parse multipart form data.

Multer works really well.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer